# Retrieve object from LINQ-to-SQL DataContext before SubmitChanges

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql

I insert a new object into LINQ-to-SQL DataContext without calling SubmitChanges() yet:

```
MyDataContext db = new MyDataContext();
MyObject newObject = new MyObject() 
{
   Id = 1,
   Name = "MyName"
};
db.MyObjects.InsertOnSubmit(newObject);
```

Now in another place in my code I want to retrieve this new object, even though it is not in the database yet. So I pass the same DataContext instance there, because I believe that the new object is cached inside it. And now I want to retrieve it. But this doesn't work:

```
MyObject newObject = db.MyObjects.Where(o => o.Id == 1).SingleOrDefault();
```

How can I do what I want? Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
db.MyObjects.SingleOrDefault(o => o.Id == 1);
```

You'd think this would be the same, but see these two connect issues:

- [LINQ-to-SQL doesn't use cache for lookup](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=340036)
- [LINQ-to-SQL still roundtrips for ID lookups (3.5SP1)](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=362313)

If that doesn't work, I know that the `.Single(o => o.Id == 1)` works in 3.5 SP1 (I don't know if I tried `.SingleOrDefault(pred)`). Apparently the `.Where(o => o.Id == 1).Single()` is fixed in 4.0 - again, I haven't tried `.Where(pred).SingleOrDefault()`.

Comment: I added the "connect" issues that explain why it may be different