# Object from LINQ-to-SQL before SubmitChanges

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql

I originally posted this as a response to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/810529/) but realised I should have asked a new one. It seems to suggest I should be able to do the following:

```
int count = Db.Countries.Count();
Country newCountry = new Country{Name = "France"};
Db.Countries.InsertOnSubmit(c);
Country getCountry = Db.Countries.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "France");
count = Db.Countries.Count();
Db.Countries.DeleteOnSubmit(c);
count = Db.Countries.Count();
```

However, on an empty table, `count` remains `0` throughout while stepping through in the debugger and `getCountry` is `null` after execution.

What am I missing?

Comment: This is little bit out-of-topic, but are those Count() operations very heavy? I have understood that it makes database query to count amount of rows. Maybe converting it to list and then take Count instead on Count() is faster?

Comment: `Count()` is quicker than converting to a list and then counting the objects in it. `select count(1) from Country` will always be quicker than `select x, y, z from Country` and then counting the results.

Answer (score 2):

LINQ-to-SQL sits in that nether-world between data in the database and objects held locally. At that point, you haven't submitted the changes to the database (`Db.SubmitChanges()`) - they only exist locally.

`Db.Countries.Count()` is executed at the database (i.e. `select COUNT(1) from Countries`) - and so the answer is 0.

It would be insanely hard (in the general case) to attempt to marry up the local deltas against the database world, so in short: don't do that. It won't work.

Comment: Okay, I get that, I guess a better way of wording the question would have been, why is MyObject newObject = db.MyObjects.Where(o => o.Id == 1).SingleOrDefault(); from the original question okay, but Count() isn't?

Comment: @enashnash actually you don't do an Id match in the original question, but there it gets... trickier ;p There is an identity manager (read: cache) that makes sure you always get the same `Country` object when the DB sees it; this is **also** used by `.{First|Single}[OrDefault](pkid-match)` and `.Where(pkid-match).{First|Single}[OrDefault]()` to avoid a round-trip. It is doing the `Id == 1` query **locally** against this cache.

Comment: Cool. In that case, when I run the following, why is `c == null` at the end?    Country c = new Country { Id = 123 };
   Db.Countries.InsertOnSubmit(c);
   c = Db.Countries.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 123);

Comment: @enashnash presumably it isn't caching against `123` as it knows that number is irrelevant until the DB over-writes it? Maybe? Certainly the identity-manager kicks in once it has *fetched* the record once - maybe that is what is missing here.

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't explain why it worked in the question I referenced and doesn't work for me. Or are you saying that the object with `Id == 1` must have already existed in the database in the referenced question?